# Java, эквивалент LINQ Select, Stream API

Tags: java

Имеется `List` объектов класса `Person`

```
public class Person {
    String name1;
    String name2;
    String name3;
    String birthdate;
    String address;
}
```

Как из этого `List` получить другой, но с некоторыми полями, к примеру, `name1`, `name2` и `address`... Желательно, используя *Stream API*.

Comment: Мне нравится iboxdb вместо linq

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так:

```
List<String> fields = persons.stream()
        .flatMap(p -> Stream.of(p.name1, p.name2, p.address))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

В этом случае и на выходе список будет, и тип у него будет `String`, а не `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос следующим образом:

```
Object[] o = persons.stream()
                 .map(r -> Arrays.asList(r.getName1(), r.getName2(),r.getAddress()))
                 .toArray();
```

Быть может, есть решение получше ?

Comment: Лучше тогда уж использовать коллектор вместо `toArray`, например так: `List<List<String>> result = persons.stream().map(r -> Arrays.asList(r.getName1(), r.getName2(),r.getAddress())).collect(Collectors.toList());`. Всё же с конкретными типами удобней работать, нежели с `Object[]`.